# error: PKGBUILD contains CRLF characters and cannot be executed

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, aur, pkgbuild

When trying to install some (though not all) packages from AUR using `yay` or `pacaur`, such as `rstudio-desktop` or `zotero`, I get the following errors (translated from German):

```
:: checking integrity of zotero...
==> ERROR: PKGBUILD contains CRLF characters and cannot be executed.
:: preparing zotero...
==> ERROR: PKGBUILD contains CRLF characters and cannot be executed.
:: failed to verify integrity or prepare zotero package
:: failed to verify integrity or prepare zotero package
```

This is right after a new install and update of Manjaro. It did not occur after another new install yesterday.

I can confirm that in `~/.cache/pacaur/` and `~/.cache/yay/` there are PKGBUILDs with `CRLF`, which also return if I delete them and retry.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the GIT configuration option `autocrlf`

Comment this line in your GIT configuration (usually `~/.gitconfig`)

```
autoclrf=true
```

and try again.